# Can I Use PlaybackParams() method in android <23 device?

Tags: android, playback

```
    PlaybackParams params = new PlaybackParams();

    public void setParams(PlaybackParams params) {
        params.setSpeed(.5f);
        this.params = params;
    }

    public PlaybackParams getParams() {
        params.setPitch(0.5f);
        return params;
    }
```

I Will Try this code but my device version will be 21 that will be error generate for :-this

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/media/PlaybackParams;
>   at
>   com.gems.fraxionapp.Music.MediaPlaybackService$MultiPlayer.(MediaPlaybackService.java:1876)at
>   com.gems.fraxionapp.Music.MediaPlaybackService.onCreate(MediaPlaybackService.java:349)at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2762)at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:151)at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1386)at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5255)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:917)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Usually the support libraries include those classes which could be backported, but there is currently no such class in the libraries.

> [Added in API level 23](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/PlaybackParams.html) means that it can't be used on previous versions.

Comment: any other library that can be set music speed rate set in android

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/PlaybackParams.html):

> Added in API level 23

So no you can not.